# Angularjs with restangular inject header after authentication

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using restangular to talk to a RESTful api.  The API requires a valid token to authenticate against.

Users in the app have logged in and have a generated token.  How do I set the default headers/intercept requests after login to include this token header.

I have been able to do it when I first bootstrap the application using  RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor but the user has not logged in at this stage and does I can not therefore insert he header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add it to the header, look at `$http.defaults` object\array. Since `Restangular` also uses $http this would affect Restangular too.

You can inject $http into the service which gets the access token and that service can add to the `defaults`.

Check `$http` documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: But is it possible to do it with RestAngular?

Comment: There is this question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867662/3836923 where the op ended up using a full request interceptor to inject the headers.